# Nginx Reverse Proxy with Gunicorn Treats Site Names Differently

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

We have a Django project that is served in production using Nginx and Gunicorn reverse-proxy setup. Everything seems to work except for one small detail. Somehow, the browser "sees" the following addresses as different sessions.

Suppose I log into the site using the `example.com` address.
Then, if I visit `https://www.example.com`, the browser does not see that the user has logged in.

When I visit `www.example.com`, I get a 404 error in the browser from Nginx.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with the way Nginx or Gunicorn are setup. Any help on how to resolve this discrepancy is appreciated.

**Nginx config**:

```
server {

    root /home/example/mysite;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/example/mysite/static/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
    }
    location /media {
        alias /home/example/mysite/media/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
    }
    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout       6000;
        proxy_send_timeout          6000;
        proxy_read_timeout          6000;
        send_timeout                6000;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/example_com_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/server.key;
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: i think you want to redirect `http www` traffic to `https non-www` ?

Comment: Perhaps. How would I do that?

Comment: i'll post my answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to redirect

```
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

you need to make changes in your `nginx vhost` config file like so:

```
# Resirect 'http www' and 'http non-www' traffic to 'https non-www'
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com  www.example.com;
    return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}

# Resirect 'https www' traffic to 'https non-www'
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}

# https://example.com
server {

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;

    root /home/example/mysite;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 512M;
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/example/mysite/static/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
    }
    location /media {
        alias /home/example/mysite/media/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
    }
    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;  # HERE review this line it should be the server IP not localhost
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout       6000;
        proxy_send_timeout          6000;
        proxy_read_timeout          6000;
        send_timeout                6000;
    }

    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/example_com_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/server.key;
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

this thread may helps you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirecting-https-www-domain-to-non-www-domain-with-nginx (my answer is based on)

and in your `settings.py`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'example.com',  # https non-www
]

# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

for more details see

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/security/#ssl-https
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure?newreg=bf8583d7f6d34236b7c6cbfb0fe315b4

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear, the first two `server` sections is what I need to add, and the third one is my existing one?

Comment: @MadPhysicist i updated my answer, try to backup the OLD config and apply this one. i kept every thing with little rearrangemt to make things more clear and readable. let me know if it works. BTW review this line `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;` and the last commented 2 lines of certbot config

Comment: It does not seem to work. Neither URL works with this config.

Comment: try `sudo nginx -t` to test config and then if OK restart it again if not can you post the error output.

Comment: `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: I am confuguring in a different file, btw. Mine is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: Inside the Nginx error log, I see this:

`2020/11/04 16:09:00 [error] 6852#6852: *3 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 119.254.155.104, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/11/04 16:09:16 [error] 6852#6852: *4 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 188.66.33.6, server: 0.0.0.0:443
`

Comment: my guess : make sure you have already SSL certification in `/home/ubuntu/ssl/*` and uncomment the last 2 lines of certbot config and try to change the localhost IP to your server IP address in this line `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;`

Comment: i recommend you this tuto https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04 on how to secure nginx with cerbot on ubuntu

Comment: Here is what happens when check the config on this file:

`sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default test failed
`

Comment: as good sysadmin practices you should create a new conf file per site, in your case it could be `/etc/nginx/sites-available/exemple.com`, try to move `exemple.con` config to a new file and keep the old one `default` it could be kind of conflict

Comment: I did. But that is just bookeeping. The config is not working, as mentioned above.

Comment: `default_server` directive was needed: `listen 443 ssl default_server; # managed by Certbot`

Comment: perfect but i guess you kept the config in the `default` file and you didn't move it to slandalone config file ? refer to this https://serverfault.com/questions/847978/best-practice-to-handle-default-server-and-public-ip-in-nginx .

Comment: No, I did move it, as you suggested.

Comment: ok never mind since it works perfectly. hope my answers were useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would you be interested in doing some freelance work for one of our projects? :-)

Comment: yes, why not :-) ? i'm already looking for opportunities and challenges.

Comment: How can I get in touch with you?

Comment: i'm reachable on skype and this my id `nizar.delleli`.

Comment: Wrote you a message. Thanks!